# Convertir de JSON a object en Java

Tags: java, json

estoy trabajando con Java. Estoy trayendo información de una Api.

```
package Main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

public class Request {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/convert?to=USD&from=COP&amount=5000";
        String response = "";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        try {
            response = peticionHttpGet(url);
            ExchageApi data = mapper.readValue(response, ExchageApi.class);
            System.out.println("La respuesta es:\n" + data.getDate());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Manejar excepción
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    public static String peticionHttpGet(String urlParaVisitar) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder resultado = new StringBuilder();
        URL url = new URL(urlParaVisitar);

        HttpURLConnection conexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conexion.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conexion.addRequestProperty("apikey", "bewZUU6yElWvqQwKxWd9TP3b5qs0byg3");
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conexion.getInputStream()));
        String linea;
        while ((linea = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            resultado.append(linea);
        }
        rd.close();
        return resultado.toString();
    }
}
```

Como verán estoy estoy utilizando la librería Jackson para convertir el response a un objeto.

Este es el response de la Api:

```
{
  "date": "2023-01-04",
  "info": {
    "rate": 0.000203,
    "timestamp": 1672847162
  },
  "query": {
    "amount": 5000,
    "from": "COP",
    "to": "USD"
  },
  "result": 1.015,
  "success": true
}
```

Y esta es la exception que me está devolviendo el código.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (String)"{    "success": true,    "query": {        "from": "COP",        "to": "USD",        "amount": 5000    },    "info": {        "timestamp": 1672863483,        "rate": 0.000203    },    "date": "2023-01-04",    "result": 1.015}"; line: 1, column: 35] (through reference chain: Main.ExchageApi["query"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1445)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1219)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:10)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4218)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3214)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3182)
    at Main.Request.main(Request.java:20)
```

Entiendo que no puede deserializar el Json porque el info y el query, los está tratando como JSON object. Entonces qué podría hacer para arreglar esto?
Les agradecería si me ayudan. Gracias.

Comment: sera que el lugar de un string debes pasarle un objeto???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenes que asegurarte de que la clase que estás utilizando para deserializar el JSON tenga una estructura adecuada para el JSON que estás recibiendo. Puede que la clase ExchageApi no tenga los mismos atributos que la respuesta de la API.

Por ejemplo, si la respuesta de la API tiene un campo date, entonces la clase ExchageApi debe tener un atributo date también.

Ejemplo:

```
public class ExchageApi {
    private String date;
    private Info info;
    private Query query;
    private double result;
    private boolean success;

    // Getters y setters para cada atributo
}

public class Info {
    private double rate;
    private long timestamp;

    // Getters y setters para cada atributo
}

public class Query {
    private int amount;
    private String from;
    private String to;

    // Getters y setters para cada atributo
}
```

Podes usar treeToValue() para convertir el JSON a un objeto de tipo ExchageApi:

```
String response = "";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(response);
ExchageApi data = mapper.treeToValue(root, ExchageApi.class);
System.out.println("La respuesta es:\n" + data.getDate());
```

nota: tenes que tener en cuenta que, además de las clases Info y Query, se deben incluir también getters y setters para las propiedades de la clase ExchageApi, de modo que Jackson pueda acceder a ellos durante la deserialización.

Comment: Gracias a tu respuesta lo puede solucionar. Muchas gracias!